# Error building cordova android project with uppercase letters in package name

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle

I have a Cordova app several years old, which has capital letters in its package name.

It was working well before, with older versions of Cordova and building in Eclipse.

Now I cannot build it with Cordova 6.1.1 and gradle. It gives errors.

I have detected that it doesn't create the folder structure and files for the app class at src folder. It should create PackageFirst folder, then inside it PackageSecond since package name is PackageFirst.PackageSecond

I generated and copied those files myself. The cordova prepare command deletes the folder, so I run prepare and then copy the folder back in. Then I try compile. But it breaks again and the build doesn't succeed, with this error:

Here is my `LogCat`.

```
BUILD FAILED    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (PackageFirst/PackageSecond/MainActivity) does not match path (packagefirst/packagesecond/MainActivity.class)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
```

I have been researching and the only solution I find, is that I need to make the package name all lowercase. Since this app is published at Google Play, I believe I cannot do that since it would be a different package name.

I have been able to build this perfectly for years until now.

Can anyone give me a solution to this problem that doesn't involve changing the package name? Thank you so much for any help!

**EDIT:**

I could get the package to build successfully, but it doesn't run on the device. With all the testing I had left uppercase in one place and lowercase in another. Once I fixed that, it built, but when trying to run it on the device, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to install apk to device: pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
```

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Comment: The specs indeed seem to require lower case. (Following URLs with a starting digit being prefixed with underscore, and minus being replace with underscore.)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly name your packages in lower case. As I can see from error you posted above

```
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name 
(PackageFirst/PackageSecond/MainActivity) does not match path 
(packagefirst/packagesecond/MainActivity.cla ss)
```

the package names have different case. This might be a cause

Comment: The package name is PackageFirst.PackageSecond, I don't know why that path is generated in lowercase at compile time. As I mentioned, since the app is several years old and installed on many devices, I cannot change the package name now. It is not a new app I am creating. The app has compiled perfectly for years until now.

Comment: did you try rebuilding the project

Comment: Yes I did. I could get it to build successfully finally, after many tests. But it still fails when trying to install it on the device with cordova run command. With error Error: Failed to install apk to device: pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]